# Calling function with ctypes or pyObjc

Tags: python, macos, pointers, ctypes, pyobjc

I want to make a call out to the IOKit framework from Python.

Here's the signature of the Objective-C function I want to call:

```
IOReturn IODisplayGetFloatParameter(io_service_t service, IOOptionBits options, CFStringRef parameterName, float *value);
```

With `pyObjc`, after importing, I'd do this:

```
brightness = 0.0
IODisplayGetFloatParameter(service, 0, kIODisplayBrightnessKey, brightness)
```

However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: depythonifying 'pointer', got 'float'
```

This is the relevant bit of the BridgeSupport file from which `pyObjc` is generating handles on `IOKit.IODisplayGetFloatParameter()`:

```
<function name='IODisplayGetFloatParameter'>
<arg type='I'/>
<arg type='L' type64='I'/>
<arg type='^{__CFString=}'/>
<arg type='^f'/>
<retval type='i'/>
```

Which leads me to believe I need to create `pyObjc` object that represents a pointer that points to a `float`, but I'm having trouble finding the relevant documentation to do so.

So, I tried to use `ctypes`, but it segfaults because I am not giving it the right `argtypes` nor passing the correct values to the function.

```
from ctypes import CDLL, c_void_p, byref, c_char_p, c_int, c_float, pointer, POINTER
from ctypes.utils import find_library

c_float_p = POINTER(c_float) 
float_ptr = c_float_p(c_float(0.0))
IOKit = CDLL(find_library('IOKit'))

IOKit.IODisplaySetFloatParameter.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, c_char_p, c_float_p]
IOKit.IODisplaySetFloatParameter(service_goes_here, 0, "brightness", float_pointer)
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to either:

1. Pass a float pointer to a `pyObjc` wrapped function?
2. Use `ctypes` to call `IODisplayGetFloatParameter`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the bridge support file is incomplete (as sadly enough most system bridge support files are).

The following code exposes this function more usefully:

```
import objc

bundle = objc.loadBundle('IOKit', bundle_path='/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework', module_globals=globals())
objc.objc.loadBundleFunctions(bundle, globals(), [
    (
        'IODisplayGetFloatParameter',
        objc._C_INT + objc._C_UINT + objc._C_NSUInteger + objc._C_ID + objc._C_PTR + objc._C_FLT,
        '',
        { 'arguments': { 3: { 'type_modifier': b'n' }}} ),
])
print(IODisplayGetFloatParameter.__metadata__())
```

This assumes that IODisplayGetFloatParameter returns a single float value by reference.

See also: https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/metadata/manual.html